# Significance of word order in "Привет мой друг" or "Привет друг мой"

Tags: порядок-слов

I am trying to say the following in russian:

> Hello, my friend.

From what I have seen from online learning videos, it seems the ordering should be:

> Привет, друг мой.

However, in my head it seemed that the following would make sense too:

> Привет, мой друг.

I have searched it online and I see it everywhere...

Are both correct or is there a rule for the ordering here? Or is it possibly convention?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's rather a convention. Changes of word order convey shades of meaning and are used for emphasis of certain elements within a sentence.

The direct order of **`мой друг`** makes the phrase sound descriptive like in a sentence **`Он - мой друг`** - **`He's a friend of mine`**.
In contrast the order of **`друг мой`** makes the phrase sound vocative, i.e. expressing an address - **`Hey, my friend!`** (NOT **`Hey, a friend of mine!`**).

**`Привет, мой друг`** is not incorrect, but less vocative than the other version.

That said, if the adjectival cluster related to the noun **`друг`** (or any noun denoting an addressee) is more elaborate, the noun itself does tend to come last, e.g. **`Привет, мой юный закадычный друг!`**

The word order in **`Привет, друг мой`** could also be an expression of a disguised reproach, disapproval, disappointment.

Comment: Yeah, it's quite hard to explain when the difference comes down to word stressing in a sentence.